# For loop isn't working C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
  char ar[4][30];
  int i=0,t;
  cout << "Enter Test cases"<< endl;
  cin>>t;
  for(i=0;i<t;i++)
  {
      gets(ar[i]);

  }  
  return 0;
}
```

From this code I want to enter multiple strings. Now let's come to the problem, when I enter the number of test cases, ar[i] accepts one string less than the test cases.I don't understand why this code isn't working.
 I am working on eclipse.

Comment: why you are not initializing the value of `t` ?

Comment: @ItbanSaeed It's being assigned with a value from input. No need to initialize.

Comment: @ItbanSaeed he is taking it as user input. The problem is that he never initialized any values in his ```ar[i][j]``` array, and uses the ```gets()``` function to retrieve the value.

Comment: I am not saying this is the reason, but its a good practice to initialize the values at start :)

Comment: You have not initialized the array

Comment: @iBug Sure, but if the input is invalid (i.e. a string), then we could potentially have an infinite loop. I mean it's undefined behavior either way, but initializing to 0 is still safer.

Comment: A quick fix could be to add `cin.ignore()` after `cin >> t`. But i would advice against using 'gets`.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `cin >> t`, there's a linefeed left in the input buffer that's being read, and is fed into the firsr `gets` invocation.

Assume this is the user input:

```
2
AAA
BBB
```

After `cin >> t`, the input buffer is

```
<ENTER>
AAA
BBB
```

So for the first time you call `gets`, it reads the Enter and returns, with `ar[1]` set to an empty string.

You probably would like to add a `cin.ignore()` or a `gets` to discard everything before the Enter (including).

```
    cin >> t;
->  gets(NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Function `gets` is extremely error-prone because you cant limit size of data stored into buffer -> buffer overflows. Don't ever use it.

Instead of that function use `fgets()`, also user can input number higher that `3` and you will write outside of bounds of an array.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char ar[4][30] = { 0, };
    int i = 0, t;
    cout << "Enter Test cases" << endl;
    cin >> t;
    cin.ignore();

    if (t > 3)
        t = 3;

    for (i = 0; i<t; i++)
    {
        fgets(ar[i], 30, stdin);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++)
    {
        std::cout << ar[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Input

```
Enter Test cases
5
test1
test2
test3
```

Output

```
test1 
test2
test3
```

If you want to insert more that `3` lines, you have to create bigger buffer,
or dynamically allocate number of rows which user entered.

---

`cin` leaves an end-line character in input buffer. You have to clear it.

- `cin.ignore()` should fix it.